# Django doesnt see cyrillic folder names and files

Tags: python, django

Django doesn't send out images with Cyrillic names from static folder and templates. Is there any setting that will enable support for non-ascii file names?

Python 3.6, OS is some linux (it doesnt say on hosting im running it at).

Static folder is defined like this

```
VUE_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend"), "dist")
```

and then in `urls.py`

```
url(r'^img/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
    'document_root': os.path.join(settings.VUE_ROOT, 'img')
})
```

edit: It works just fine on my pc with `runserver` command, but on server it doesnt load these files with cyrillic in its name.

Comment: What versions of Django and python are you running? What OS is it running on? What is the system's default codepage? How do you define the static folders? Show us some code, please: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that my files were created on Windows, so their names were using cp1251 encoding, but Linux and django only work with utf-8, so i had to change them. Now it works just fine.